# How to get alpha of background color in HTML?

Tags: html, css, background-color, alpha, getcomputedstyle

The below feels a bit overengineered, is there a direct accessor?

```js
const bg = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.source')).backgroundColor
document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML =
  bg.startsWith('rgba') ? bg.replace(/rgba\(\d+\, \d+\, \d+\, (\d(\.\d+)?)\)/g, '$1') : 1
```

```css
.source {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.44);
}
```

```html
<div class="source" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"></div>
Alpha:
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: You could access an inline-style from `<HTMLElement>.style.<property>` but for computed styles, it seems `getComputedStyle` is the way to go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Thank you @wlh! I was afraid that is the case.